# regular expression can not find all

Tags: python, python-re

The following code can be run directly. What I want is to return a list: `l = [1,2]` (string). However, what I got is the string between the very first "begin" and the last "end". Even though this is one of the expected results. I can not find it out what happened.

```
import re

text = r'''

\begin{figure}
1
\end{figure}

aaa

\begin{figure}
2
\end{figure}

'''

pattern = r"\\begin{figure}([\s\S^f]*)\\end{figure}"
r = re.findall(pattern, text)


print(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` operator captures as many characters as possible. This means it captures until the last occurence of `\end{figure}` If you only want to capture as many characters as needed, use `*?` instead: `pattern = r"\\begin{figure}([\s\S^f]*?)\\end{figure}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern had multiple problems.  Here is a working version:

```
text = r'''

\begin{figure}
1
\end{figure}

aaa

\begin{figure}
2
\end{figure}

'''

pattern = r"\\begin\{figure\}(?:(?!\\end\{figure\}).)*?(\d+).*?\\end\{figure\}"
nums = re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(nums)  # ['1', '2']
```

Notes: I am using a tempered dot to match the content after the leading `\begin{figure}` marker without crossing over the closing `\end{figure}` marker.  I also use dot all mode here, so that `.*` can match across newlines.  In addition, you had some regex metacharacters, such as `{`, which needed to be escaped by backslash.